# Embed Php in Html

Tags: php, html, embed

i have a code which checks if username and password match and exist in database, and i got an html document below it, which is the login form. The problem is if the user's login credentials are incorrect the statement **Invalid credentials** gets printed at top of the screen, I want it above the Username box in Html. Please help :)

```
if($username == $dbUserName && $password == $dbPassword) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
    header('Location: user.php');
} else {
    echo "<b><i>Invalid credentials</i><b>";
}
```

Comment: Save the text in a variable and output the variable where you want it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Save your error message into a variable then print it wherever you want.

your php code:

```
if($username == $dbUserName && $password == $dbPassword) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
    header('Location: user.php');
} else {
    $login_error =  "<b><i>Invalid credentials</i><b>";
}
```

in your html part:

```
<div id="log_err"> <?= $login_error; ?> </div>
<input type="text" name="username">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the whole thing in a function and then call it This way :

```
function check_credentials() {
    if($username == $dbUserName && $password == $dbPassword) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
        header('Location: user.php');
    } else {
        echo "<b><i>Invalid credentials</i><b>";
    }
}
```

And you could call your function where ever you want in your form.

Answer (score 0):

As above mentioned,you can handle error using function,but to do it very simple and clear,define variable for the error,and put it above username input,like below :

PHP

```
if($username == $dbUserName && $password == $dbPassword) 
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
header('Location: user.php');
    }
else 
{
    $error =  "<b><i>Invalid credentials</i><b>";
}
```

HTML

```
<?php echo $error = " "; ?>
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

but for sure,you will need to define function for the errors,if any error occured return false,for example :

```
    function LoginErrors($username , $password) 
    {
    if(strlen($username) < 4 )
     {
    echo "you must choose at least 4 character for username!";
    return false;
}
    if(strlen($password) < 6)
     {
    echo "you must choose at least 6 character for password!";
return false;
     }
return true;
    }
```

PHP

```
   if($username == $dbUserName && $password == $dbPassword) 
    {
if(LoginErrors($_POST['username] , $_POST['password]) == true )
{
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
    header('Location: user.php');
}
}
```

HTML

```
<?php LoginErrors(); ?>
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

Comment: Thanks for you'r concern..I will surely add these errors for my registration page.